# Magento The last "learn more" and "add to cart" buttons do not work in Firefox

Tags: php, javascript, magento

The last "learn more" and "add to cart" buttons do not work on the following page in Firefox: http://animalnecessity.com/all-natural-pet-care-supplement-products/ocuglo-rx-dog-eye-care.html. There are no javascript errors in console and I see no applicable PHP errors in logs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The buttons aren't clickable because the product items in the ul are floated.

You need to change the inline style on the `.products-grid` ul element from `display:inline` to `display:block`. (this is likely in your list.phtml file)